# handling an empty dataframe in 'if' condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am downloading some data from a website and storing it as a pandas dataframe. After this I am comparing one column of the dataframe with some values in 'if condition':

```
       crest=float(crest_day.Crest)
       if (crest>=Response_record):
          print ("It's record flood")
       elif(crest>=Response_major):
          print ("Flood_Response=Major Flood Stage")
       else:
          print("No Flood")
```

this does not work if sometime the website return an empty dataframe, means the website has no data for the specific date, so 'crest_day' becomes empty.My program starts throwing an error as follows:

```
       TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

'Response_record' & 'Response_major' variables are float.

I have also tried many other methods like pd.to_numeric and astype(float) for converting 'crest_day.Crest' to float but none works. crest_day has two columns 'Date' and 'Crest'

Comment: `crest=crest_day.Crest.astype(float)` instead of `crest=float(crest_day.Crest)`.

Comment: If you encounter errors using the `.astype` method, please edit your question and add the error encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fillna() function while preparing your dataframe. Consider you have a dataframe crest which some times is empty. for comparison create a dataframe as follows:

```
new_crest=crest.fillna(0)
if (new_crest.Crest>=Response_record)
    print ("It's record flood")
```

Comment: thanks but crest_day is an empty dataframe i.e. length of this dataframe is zero, it doesnot have even 'na' entries, so fillna(0) is not working, I've tried already

Answer (score 0):

in that case try this:

```
   if ((len(crest)>0)&(crest>=Response_record)):
      print ("It's record flood")
   elif((len(crest)>0)&(crest>=Response_major)):
      print ("Flood_Response=Major Flood Stage")
   else:
      print("No Flood")
```